# Is there any way to force save download with one click from external domain?

Tags: html, apache, redirect, http-headers, cross-domain

I'm trying somehow help my users saving files without "Save link as" option in browser.
Problem is that file is on domain abc.com and link is on abcd.com 
Is it really impossible ? The tutorials on website with instruction doesn't help much, they just want one click download :-)

Thank you everyone.

Comment: What should it do instead? It's not possible to change how the browser downloads files, whether on the same domain or another.

Comment: Hi. Browser opens it as media and starting playing in the browser, as these files are considered as video files by major browsers :( and I need them to show save dialog

Comment: Maybe I could use headless Chrome on server side ? but i'm still won't get file size to transfer it, right ?